# What happens if you die in a dream before you die in the dream within?

Tags: inception

Why do Arthur and Eames have to arrange kicks in their respective dream levels? If all the characters want to return to reality, shouldn't a death in the first dream level (Yusuf's) suffice?

Comment: Spirit roaming forever !

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR - Yes, but...**

I'll just quote [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inception) here, since it gives a fairly concise answer to this question. Note that I haven't watched the movie in a few months, so if this is wrong feel free to correct me.

> While death in a dream would, under normal circumstances, cause the
>   dreamer to wake up, the sedatives used to stabilize the dreams would
>   not allow that. Thus, death during the mission will result in entering
>   "Limbo", an expanse of infinite raw subconscious from which it is very
>   difficult to escape.

Edit - In Limbo itself, death does allow you to wake up. It seems that either the same rules regarding the sedative don't apply, or the sedative is wearing off, when they kill themselves in Limbo.

Comment: I'd rather say the escape from Limbo by dead only works because on the 3rd level they _didn't_ get sedated but merely shot, or not sedated as strongly, such that from the perspective of level 3 they "woke up" by the "usual" dying...